# Customising accessHost value in Dynamic Storage service key

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I have a dynamic storage service set up on Swisscom with the default service key. There is a value within that JSON which is access host:

```
"accessHost": "ds11s3.swisscom.com"
```

I was wondering if there was any way that this value can be customised to a more appropriate naming convention for us. Something like:

```
"accessHost": "ds11s3.ournamehere.net"
```

Is there any way we can achieve this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is not possible as the hostname is part of the signature generated for each request.